# Angular project takes long time to reload changes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my Angular project I am serving with the following command:

```
ng serve --ssl --configuration=development
```

Problem is the whole project builds again upon updating anything in the project and takes a long time even to see a small change. Is there any other command or flag that can be used for faster reloads and changes?

If I do `ng-serve --ssl` it comes back with an error:

```
Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many variables as to why it may be building slowly, including your personal definition of what a "long time" is.

To answer your question,

> Is there any other command or flag that can be used for faster reloads and changes?

Answer is... Maybe? There are a few flags you could try to improve the speed of your builds and if you feel as though the reloading for every small change is unnecessary you can address that too.

For increased build performance you can try enabling hot module replacement by setting the flag `--hmr=true` which depending on your project can result in a considerable increase in build performance. Also if you don't care about package optimization during development you could disable it by setting the flag `--optimization=false` which should also decrease the overall build time.

Also if you don't like the constant reloading every time a small change is made you can disable the live reload with the `--liveReload=false` flag or establish a longer poll duration with the poll flag `--poll=60000` (in milliseconds).

Although I'd perhaps consider trying to optimize your builds before fiddling with the live reload stuff first. Perhaps that alone may be sufficient for your building needs.

Comment: Thanks, in what way do you mean optimising builds?

Comment: You can disable optimization so during the build process it doesn't waste time going through your entire code base to remove things like comments, dead code, white space, etc.. and instead just delivers you the code the way you wrote it. Given your package size will increase, but your build time will decrease.

Comment: In terms of long time it is around: 81751ms, would you say thats correct? the project uses apis etc

Comment: For a live reload 81751ms is definitely not most desirable, but it's all kind of relative. I've had better and I've had worse.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had the same problem after creating a new "local" configuration and setting optimization=false was the solution.  I had copied the "production" config in `angular.json` and didn't know about this.  I would have copied the default ("dev"?) config but there doesn't seem to be one; Angular must just have that internally.  In my case, on a small app, `ng serve myProject` took about 1 second to live reload and `ng serve myProject --configuration=local` was taking 15-20.